# JSON does not validate

Tags: json, string, validation

Below is code that I am trying to validate on json. but i keep getting "expected string" error. please help

```
 {
'auth.login': {
    'url': 'https: //api.optionshouse.com/m',
    'params': {
        'EZMessage': {
            'action': 'auth.login',
            'data': {
                'userName': 'rspt',
                'password': 'xxx'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is "JSON Validator"? How do you try to parse?

Comment: Use a tool like [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to find the specific problem.

Comment: I use http://json.parser.online.fr/ which gives instant feed back.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I think that's what he's using, but it just says "expecting string", it isn't specific like "don't use single quotes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not allow single-quoted strings.

You need to use double quotes.

Comment: thanks - yest it was a double quotes thing. I did use JSON Lint.